# PHP MySQL INSERT Value return Primary Key of inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use the following statement to insert photograph information into photograph table:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Photographs(Genre, Name, Photographer, Camera, location) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isiis', $genre, $name, $photographer, $camera, $location);
$stmt->execute();
```

After successful insert I would like to get the auto incremented primary key value of the photograph table and insert into a junction table (for my many to many relationship) as such:

```
$stmtPhotoGenre = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO PhotoGenre(idPhotograph, Genre) VALUES(?,?)");
$stmtPhotoGenre->bind_param('ii', $idPhotograph);
```

Is there a way to get the id of the last insert using MySQL or PHP? I thought of using timestamp but there is always a chance that two people can be inserting at the same time and some sort cross mapping could happen. Any solution or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mysqli_insert_id](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) — Returns the auto generated id used in the last query

Answer (score 2):

You can get it back using this class variable named [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

It looks like all you have to do is access `$stmtPhotoGenre->insert_id;`, or run `mysqli_insert_id($link);` if you're not going the OOP route.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID` function will meet your needs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id